# Is there any way to install racket documentation only for specific package

Tags: racket, raco

I ran `raco setup` with `--no-docs` option. Now I want documentation for some packages. Is there any way to install documentation of only specific packages?

Comment: Does `raco setup --pkgs <your-package-name>` work?